# How to use ichartjs in CrossUI?

Tags: javascript, rad

I am new to the CrossUI.I need guidelines about including the ichartjs(Charting tool) with the CrossUI.I have tried the including part as suggested in the CrossUI forum but still i am getting ReferenceError:iChart in not defined the browser console.Could you please anyone give the solution for this problem?.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to add an xui.UI.Div, and give it a specific dom ID.

```
iniComponents : function(){
    // [[Code created by CrossUI RAD Tools
    var host=this, children=[], append=function(child){children.push(child.get(0));};

    append((new xui.UI.Div())
    .setHost(host,"ctl_div10")
    // the node for ichrtjs rendering
    .setDomId("canvasDiv")
    .setLeft(20)
    .setTop(20)
    .setWidth(510)
    .setHeight(340)
    );

    return children;
    // ]]Code created by CrossUI RAD Tools
}
```

And you can use this id to load any chart of IChartJS.

Of course, you must incoude IChartJS script in your main html file first.

Here's an online demo: http://www.crossui.com/RAD/XUIWorkSpace/IChartJS_Demo

Comment: Thank you for your quick response, actually i can do this way before my posting.But what i want is i have seen the example in cross ui forum with this url 
"www.crossui.com/Forum/how-to-incorporate-3rd-party-scripts-such-as-a-leafletjs-map-t201.html".In that what is the use of xui.include i.e.)
 
            "xui.CSS.includeLink("http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.2/leaflet.css");
            xui.include("L","http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.2/leaflet.js",function(){
                ns._buildMap();
            });"

Comment: If i do this way for leaflet map and use the .js file as the reference in another html file without referring the leaflet.js and leaflet.css in the html file then it is working fine.If i do the same way for ichartjs only i am getting "ReferenceError:iChart is not defined".
How can i do this way for ichartjs?. and also what is the "L" in the leaflet map example what should i use for ichartjs?

Comment: In real app, you should always including js lib in html file.

And "L" is leaflet's root namespace.